# Deserializing JSON with indexed array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, deserialization

I'm very new to working with JSON and am dealing wtih a return from an API which I can't change the formatting of.  The return example is : (actual urls have been removed)

```
{
"body":
    {
    "link":
        {"linkurl": ["www.google.com"]}
    },
"error": null,
"message": "Data Retrieved successfully",
"status": true
}
```

I am using the Newtonsoft.Json library with MVC 3, in VS2010.

My class is:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class LinksJSON
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string link{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string error { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public bool status { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm deserializing it with :

```
private static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>(string url) where T : new()
    {
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
        }
    }

    public string CheckJSONLink()
    {

        var url = "<api url-removed for security>";

        var outObj = _download_serialized_json_data<LinksJSON>(url);



        return outObj.Link;
    }
```

However I'm trying to get the value of `linkurl`, which is an indexed array within `Link`.

How would I access this information?

Comment: btw, i can access all other fields ( error, message and status with no problem ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following classes:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LinksJSON
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public body body { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool status { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class body
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public link link { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class link
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] linkurl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing: similar to above

    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
        public class LinksJSON
        {
            [JsonProperty]
            public bodylinkdetails body;
            [JsonProperty]
            public bool status;
            [JsonProperty]
            public string message;
            [JsonProperty]
            public string error;
        }

        public class bodylinkdetails
        {
            public link link;
        }

        public class link
        {
            public string[] linkurl;
        }

Answer (score 2):

You did not setup your class to match the JSON, your class says that `link` is a simple string, you your example shows it as a complex type.

In order to properly deserialize it as you expect, you will have to modify your class to match the JSON. Specifically `link` should be an instance of a class.

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well, as it prompted the discussion with their team to get the proper class structure to deserialize.